# Exception Value: need more than 1 value to unpack

Tags: django, drop-down-menu

i have a problem with django-smart_selects:

Model:

```
class Demande_Expertise(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    material = models.ForeignKey("Material")
    categorie =  ChainedForeignKey("Category",
                              chained_field="material",
                              chained_model_field="name",
                              show_all=False,
                              auto_choose=True)                         
    droits_acces = models.CharField(_('val_champ'), max_length=150, choices = DROITS)
    groupe = models.ForeignKey(Group, blank = True, null= True, default = None)
    etat = models.CharField(_('val_champ'), max_length=150, choices = ETAT, default = '2')



class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    expert = models.ForeignKey(Expert, null=True, blank=True, default = None)
    description = models.TextField(_('description'), blank=True)



class Material(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(_('description'), blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, verbose_name=_('category'))
    created = models.DateField(_("creation date"), auto_now_add=True)
```

I get the error

```
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value: need more than 1 value to unpack

 File "C:\03_08\monprojet\..\monprojet\material\models.py", line 48, in Demande
_Expertise
    auto_choose=True)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\smart_selects\db_fields.py", line 20, in __init__
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

what does it means ?

Answer (score 0):

Accorind to [the source code of django-smart-select](https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects/blob/5179f821854acd3aed25886c4f2dfd366fee041e/smart_selects/db_fields.py#L20). Following is executed.

```
self.app_name, self.model_name = to.split('.')
```

`to` is model name you passed.

```
>>> app_name, model_name = "Category".split('.')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
>>> app_name, model_name = "app_name.Category".split('.')
>>>
```

---

```
>>> a, b = ['a', 'b']
>>> a, b = ['a']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

---

You need to pass model name as form of `app_name.model_name`.

```
categorie =  ChainedForeignKey("material.Category",
                               ....)
```

Comment: Thanks, I have no error but I still can not bind a material and category

Comment: class Demande_Expertise(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    material = models.ForeignKey("Material")
    categorie =  ChainedForeignKey("material.Category",
                              chained_field="material",
                              chained_model_field="name",
                              show_all=False,
                              auto_choose=True) 

and for the template
{% csrf_token%} {% for field in form %} {{ field }} {% endfor %}

the dropdown category is not filled ??